# Run multiple queries in Codeigniter model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I do have a Codeigniter model function to insert data to two tables. I used this kind of setup.

```
function abc{
            {query 1}
            {query 2}
            return 'success'
            }
```

but sometimes the function returns success without executing the second query. How to prevent it?

Comment: your first query is might be breaking, add log for each query and check in phpMyadmin.

Comment: use [CI transaction](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
function abc() {
    $result1 = query1_function();
    if ($result1) {
        $result2 = query2_function();
    } else {
        return 'fail on query 1';
    }
    if ($result1 && $result2) {
        return 'success';
    }
    return 'fail on query 2';
}
```

Of course, your `query1_function` and `query2_function` would need to return the `$this->db->insert_id()` after call to the `$this->db->insert()` function.